# Question on algebraic integers.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I'm currently studying algebraic extension and I found this problem: if $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$ is an algebraic integer prove $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$. So far I know from the definition that if $\alpha = \frac{a}{b}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq 0$ we can deduce $b^{n}\alpha$ is also an algebraic integer. I've couldn´t go any further.

Comment: See the rational roots theorem.

Comment: Or, if $p$ is a prime factor of $b$ that is not a factor of $a$ (when it should have gotten cancelled), what can you say about the denominator (resp. numerator) of $P(\alpha)$, where $P(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is a monic polynomial.